# Is there documentation for the different user license types within each edition of scratch org?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, userlicense

I need to know which user license types are available in developer scratch org vs enterprise scratch org vs group scratch org vs professional scratch org. These are all the types of editions scratch orgs can have. I just need to know how the user license types vary between them.

I specifically need which user license types are available and how many, but I cannot find documentation on this anywhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the basic out-of-the-box configuration, it looks like Developer Edition gets the following:

```
Chatter External                    500     
Chatter Free                        5,000
Company Communities                 10
Customer Community                  5
Customer Community Login            5
Customer Community Plus             5
Customer Community Plus Login       5    
Customer Portal Manager Custom      5    
Customer Portal Manager Standard    5    
External Identity                   5    
Force.com - App Subscription        2
Force.com - Free                    2
Gold Partner                        3
High Volume Customer Portal         10
Identity                            10
Partner App Subscription            2
Partner Community                   5 
Partner Community Login             5
Salesforce                          2
Salesforce Platform                 3
Silver Partner                      2    
Work.com Only                       3 
XOrg Proxy User Active              2
```

And Enterprise/Professional gets:

```
Salesforce                      5
High Volume Customer Portal     5
Chatter Free                    5,000
Chatter External                500
Company Communities             10
```

---

Note that these limits are subject to change at any time, but these are the values I got from orgs created in the past 30 days.

Comment: I checked around and this is the exact information. The documentation on this area definitely does not do a good job and should have been more explicit.